# How to add separate radio button in Symfony2 Forms?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form for setting mysql, sqlite and postgre configuration. I arrange them on separate tabs (using bootstrap). As well, I have an form field: type of connection (with the three choices). For this I use the choice field type.

How to instead create a radio button for each tabs of database?

Comment: You have to loop on the FormView children as explained on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925451/symfony-2-6-render-individual-choice-field-radio-checkbox-by-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [`expanded`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#expanded) option to true on your `choice` field.

For example, in your form type:

```
$builder->add('connection_type', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array('MySQL' => 'mysql', 'SQLite' => 'sqlite', 'PostgreSQL' => 'postgresql'),
    'expanded' => true,
));
```

Comment: And next? How to split radio buttons?

Comment: What do you mean by split? You want only one radio button per tab? Can you show us the twig code you have or maybe a screen shot explaining the result you expect?