# Symfony 2.6 - render individual choice field (radio, checkbox) by name

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

How can I render an individual field (single radio/checkbox input field) in Twig in Symfony 2.6?

Let's say I have a simple form:

```
class TransportType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
            $builder->add('transport', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'road' => 'Car/bus',
                    'train' => 'Train',
                ),
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false
            ));
    }
```

In previous Symfony2 versions I could just use:

```
{{ form_widget(form.transport.road) }}
{{ form_widget(form.transport.train) }}
```

to render individual radio buttons, but it doesn't seem to work anymore. I know I can use:

```
{{ form_widget(form.transport[0]) }}
{{ form_widget(form.transport[1]) }}
```

but it's less flexible. Of course I can iterate over the collection and check for name, but this seems like unnecessary hassle. Isn't there an easier way?

I tried `offsetGet` (which is supposed to `return a child by name`), but it also works only with array index.

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
{% for key, transportItem in form.transport.children %}
    {{ form_widget(transportItem) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

here my solution i used in my own project

```
{{form_label(form.transport)}}

 {% for key, item in form.transport.children %}
    <div class="custom-radio">
        <label for="{{item.vars.id}}">{{item.vars.label}}</label>
        <input 
            type="radio" 
            value="{{item.vars.value}}" 
            id=" {{item.vars.id}}" 
            name="{{item.vars.full_name}}" 
           {{ item.vars.checked ? 'checked' : '' }} 
        >
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

or you can use a form theming

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{%- block choice_widget_expanded -%}
    {%- for child in form %}
        <div class="custom-radio">
            {{- form_label(child) -}}
            {{- form_widget(child) -}}
        </div>
    {% endfor -%}
{%- endblock choice_widget_expanded -%}


{{form_widget(form)}}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the ChoiceView does not have id and full_name properties. 
https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/5.x/ChoiceList/View/ChoiceView.php

I think you would have to take the name from the FormView object and build the id from the id from the FormView with the key of the current choice view.
Something like: form.transport.id ~'_'~ key for the id and from.transport.full_name as the name will be the same for all choices.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is not possible with the latest versions of Symfony (i.e. >= 2.6). I recall in previous versions, when the form builder displayed the `choices` array, it was generating the choices like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="road">Car/Bus</option>
    <option value="train">Train</option>
</select>
```

This, however, has been changed in the recent versions to the following:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">Car/Bus</option>
    <option value="1">Train</option>
</select>
```

The selected option is then normalized and then you get the expected `value` you've set in the `FormType` class. You can read more about normalization [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#about-model-and-view-transformers).

Also, If you write `{{ debug(form.transport) }}` in Symfony >= 2.6, you can see the form/field array and what you can use from it.